# NoSuchMethodError on Saxon configuration

Tags: java, saxon, xmlbeans

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>  net.sf.saxon.Configuration.setDOMLevel(I)V
>       at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.xquery.saxon.XBeansXQuery.
> (XBeansXQuery.java:55)

Does any of you guys have faced [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbFKF.png) error before?
I'm not sure if it has something to do with the version of xmlBeans and Saxon
my dependencies are:
xmlbeans-xpath : 2.4
xmlbeans : 2.4
saxon: 8.7

Comment: Rather than just providing an exception, you should provide the code that is causing the exception so that we can help. Just saying "here's an error" makes it very difficult to provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

A `NoSuchMethodError` generally indicates that you are running code that was compiled against one version of a library (in this case, Saxon) and that you are executing it with a different version of the same library, in which there has been an incompatible change. Check which version of Saxon `XMLBeans` requires, and make sure you have that version on the *classpath*.